# Present perfect or past tense in the first part?

Tags: grammaticality, past-tense, present-perfect

Are the following two sentences grammatically correct?

1. Mark has been injured while he was training.
2. While Mark was training, he has injured himself.

I am particularly interested in the correct tense of the verb “injure”.

Comment: I think you need to be consistent -- use simple or perfect in both clauses, not a mix. E.g. "Mark was injured while he was training."

Comment: Although for some reason, #1 doesn't seem as bad as #2.

Comment: _He has injured himself_ does **not** mean the same thing as _He has been injured._

Comment: Is he *still* injured, or has he recovered? If the latter, the simple past is likely preferred.

Comment: I think we need to know the context. I can imagine the first being used when reporting something that has just happened and which is going to ruin your plans. But it depends if it's part of a past-tense narrative (in which case it's less suitable), in something that's otherwise present tense, standing alone, or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

In the first sentence, "while he was training" correctly modifies "injured", so the first sentence is correct in an appropriate context.

In the second sentence, "while he was training" attempts to modify present tense "he *has* injured himself", but that does not work.